# How can I do a $geoNear aggregation on embedded documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, geo

I have a MongoDB collection called services, each of which has more than one embedded location.

It looks something like this:

```
{
  name: "example",
  locations: [
    {
      coordinates: [0, 0] 
    },
    {
      coordinates: [0, 0] 
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to use an aggregation to `$unwind` the data structure so each location is treated as a seperate document, and then sort each one based on distance from a user-supplied point using `$geoNear`, like this:

```
db.collection("services").aggregate([
  { $unwind : "$locations" }
  { $geoNear: {
    near: [0, 0],
    distanceField: "distance"
  }},
```

However, naturally, $geoNear wants to be the [first thing in an aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#behavior) and I am struggling to understand how it could work without $unwind coming first.

Creating the index *seems* to succeed but when I try to run it I get a "unable to find index for $geoNear query" error.

**Can I somehow run an aggregation and then run another aggregation on the results?**

**Or, is there a way to do this without an aggregation?**

Importantly, simply changing the data schema isn't easy to do because mongo is being used a something like a search index, and the data itself is coming from a relational database elsewhere.

I could perhaps look at creating a second collection that pre-unwinds the data? Does MongoDB have some kind of callbacks that could make this less painful?

Answer (score 0):

The geoNear query requires a special 2d or 2dsphere index.  The index will relate each location to a document.  If a single document contains several location, all of the locations will refer to the same document.

The geoNear query then selects documents by searching the index and returns documents in order from nearest to farthest.

A single document will not be returned multiple times even if it has multiple locations.

While unwinding does permit you to deal with each location in a separate document, there are not indexes on the documents in the pipeline after $unwind, so geoNear cannot function.

The only way to use geoNear to examine all the elements in the array would be to output them to a temporary collection after unwind, create a 2dsphere index on the temp collection and then use geoNear with that collection.

You can calculate a reasonable approximation of the distance between two points using the [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula.